# Centre a UIImageView inside a CGRect

Tags: ios, layout, uiimageview, cgrect

I would like to centre a `UIImageView` inside a rectangular region on an iOS screen. The location and dimensions of the rectangle are determined at runtime and are represented by a `CGRect`. The image has already been drawn but has to move to the centre of the rectangular region at runtime. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you are using auto-layout (the default) then you would use layout constraints. You should be able to set up layout constraints in IB that would keep the image view centered even if it changes size, without requiring any custom code.

Simply Select the view in IB, choose the button at the right that gives you a popup titled "Add New Alignment Constraints" and click the checkboxes "Horizontal Center in Container" and "Vertical Center in Container". Then click the "Add constraints" button at the bottom of the popup.

Comment: My app was developed before auto layout came into existence so I could rule out the use of its constraints.

Comment: Ok, then set up the "struts and strings" style layout the same way.

Comment: I did not know about "struts and strings" when I was developing the app. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the change to occur instantaneously, you should simply be able to change the frame for the image view to your desired CGRect:

```
imageView.frame = rect
```

This is assuming your UIImageView autosizes and/or has the correct aspect ratio. If not, you should adjust your CGRect accordingly. Alternatively, you can look into animating the frame property.

If you're just going to be doing this when the view initially loads, it would be much easier center the image with Auto Layout by horizontally and vertically centering it in its container, as Duncan C suggested.

Comment: My app was developed before auto layout came into existence so I could rule out the use of its constraints.